# Colab not working on phones when cell set to display form only

Tags: google-colaboratory

Google Colab does not open notebooks where a cell is set to display a form only.

See [this example](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/borisdayma/9dc3515a0bd40388d6b30c7d76cfcf94/bug-form-on-phones.ipynb) which works correctly on a computer but not on a phone.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it with these steps:

- open the notebook in raw format
- remove the lines `"cellView": "form",`
- edit your title lines such as `"#@title my_title {display-mode: \"form\"}\n",`

You can see [my commit](https://github.com/borisdayma/huggingtweets/commit/1fb6ea266498b2dc06d68494702b65c1dd4bb93e) as an example.

Obviously this is very inconvenient so a real fix is needed but this temporary solution should be helpful in the meantime